# Pandas dataframe selection

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two step filtering process on my data:

```
data = data[data['Volume']>1]
data = data[data['Open']>0]
```

I tried to do this:

```
data = data[data['Open']>0 and data['Volume']>1]
```

But I get `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Is there an elegant way to perform this operation in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` and wrap the conditions using `()`:

```
data = data[(data['Open']>0) & (data['Volume']>1)]
```

You should use `&`, `|` and `~` for `and`, `or` and `not` respectively. The parentheses are required due to operator precedence.

The problem with `and`, `or` and `not` is that the returned result is an array of booleans, which it doesn't understand how to interpret as it's expecting a scalar value.

This is why you get the error returned, if you added `any()` or `all()` this would return a single boolean value which it would accept